# Python: How to subclass while calling parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclassing

I have the following class which is being subclassed:

```
class ConnectionManager(object):

    def __init__(self, type=None):

        self.type = None

        self.host = None
        self.username = None
        self.password = None
        self.database = None
        self.port = None


    def _setup_connection(self, type):
        pass
```

I then have a specific manager for various database. And I can call those like this:

```
c = MySQLConnectionManager()
c._setup_connection(...)
```

However, is there a way to do the following instead?

```
c = ConnectionManager("MySQL")
c._setup_connection(x,y,z) # this would call the MySQLConnectionManager, 
                           # not the ConnectionManager
```

Basically, I want to be able to call things in reverse order, is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should be implementing `__new__()` - that lets you create and return an instance of an appropriate subclass, based on the parameters that were passed.  `__init__()` is too late to do any such thing, the object has already been created.

Comment: @jasonharper could you please show how that would be done in the above?

Comment: @jasonharper what would I return in the `__new__` method? Would it be `return MySQLConnectionManager()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use the static factory method pattern. Leaving out non-relevant code for brevity:

```
class ConnectionManager:
    # Create based on class name:

    @staticmethod
    def factory(type):
        if type == "mysql": return MySqlConnectionManager()
        if type == "psql": return PostgresConnectionManager()
        else:
            # you could raise an exception here
            print("Invalid subtype!")

class MySqlConnectionManager(ConnectionManager):
    def connect(self): print("Connecting to MySQL")

class PostgresConnectionManager(ConnectionManager):
    def connect(self): print("Connecting to Postgres")
```

Use the factory method to create subclass instances:

```
psql = ConnectionManager.factory("psql")
mysql = ConnectionManager.factory("mysql")
```

Then use your subclass objects as needed:

```
psql.connect()  # "Connecting to Postgres"
mysql.connect()  # "Connecting to MySQL"
```

Comment: thanks, this certainly seems like the easiest approach. Out of curiosity, what would be the difference between using this approach and using the `__new__()` item?

Comment: also, what does the line `factory = staticmethod(factory)` do?

Comment: @HenryH updated to use the `staticmethod` decorator, which allows us to call the decorated method `factory` from an uninstantiated object.

Comment: Classes don’t need to explicitly inherit from object in python 3.

Comment: @HenryH there are a few good reasons to use a static factory method rather than use the constructor (`__new__`) - one important distinction is that the static factory method can be meaningfully named.